# GETDATE() showing Wrong time

Tags: sql-server, web-config, global-asax, getdate

```
Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
```

I want to return the time for India Standard Time and set the time in SQL Server

Comment: What is your question here, you forgot to ask one when you posted your "question". `GETDATE()`, however, doesn't have a culture (format I assume?). It returns a `datetime`. `date`, `time` and `datetime(2)` data types don't have a format stored as part of their datatype; they are unambiguous provided you are treating them as the datatype they are.

Comment: My date time is returning 4.30hr Lessthan what i have set in Web,conf as 
 <globalization culture="en-IN" uiCulture="en-IN" />  Since time now is 13.09 HR is takes 10.39HR when i run GETDATE().

Comment: culture != timezone

Comment: As per the documentation of `GETDATE()`: *"Returns the current database system timestamp as a datetime value without the database time zone offset. This value is derived from the operating system of the computer on which the instance of SQL Server is running."* `GETDATE()` is returning the date and time of the server, which means when you're running it you're getting the a date and time respective for it. You'd be far better off using something like `SYSUTCDATETIME()` and then translating the time to your local timezone.

Comment: If you want to change the date and time of your SQL Server, you need to RDP to the host machine, and change the date and time settings on the operating System (not SQL Server, as SQL server uses the operating system's time). Of course, if it's an Azure server, then you can't do that.